# How can I implement a Rails-like :has_many :through in Entity Framework?

Tags: entity-framework-6

My application has "Mainlines" which have many "Builds", which, in turn, have many "Releases". In VB.NET (C# is not allowed):

```
Partial Public Class Mainline
    Public Property MainlineID As Integer
    Public Property Designation As String
    ...
    Public Overridable Property Builds As ICollection(Of Build)
End Class

Partial Public Class Build
    Public Property BuildID As Integer
    Public Property Version As String
    ...
    Public Overridable Property Mainline As Mainline
    Public Overridable Property Releases As ICollection(Of Release)
End Class

Partial Public Class Release
    Public Property ReleaseID As Integer
    Public Property Version As Integer
    Public Property ReleaseDate As Date
    ...
    Public Overridable Property Build As Build
End Class
```

I've been doing Rails for many years now, so that's the terminology I know to talk about what I want, but I need a `:has_many :through` on Mainlines to get to Releases through Builds. I want to know how to get to this syntax:

```
db.Mainlines.Find(4).Releases
```

In terms of SQL, I want to do is this:

```
SELECT rels.*
FROM dbo.Releases rels,
dbo.Mainlines mls,
dbo.Builds blds
WHERE mls.MainlineID = blds.Mainline_MainlineID
AND blds.BuildID = rels.Build_BuildID
AND mls.MainlineID = 4
ORDER BY rels.ReleaseDate ASC
```

Specifically, I'm trying to look up all the "Releases" on a "Mainline" (which may have a different "Build") so that I can track what's changed (in models that are children of Releases) over time. (It would be nice to have a NuGet package for EF like an acts_like_tree gem for Rails, but tracking by latest previous date will get me close enough.)

It seems like there should be something that could be done, either in the class definition, or in the `OnModelCreating` section of the `DbContext` class, but I can't find anything, anywhere, that looks like an example of what I'm trying to do. It seems so basic, I'm pretty sure I'm just missing it.

There's a bunch of code at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591620#ManyToMany) that shows Fluent API examples for stuff that I thought EF did automatically, which is confusing. (It makes me think that those docs are for EF4.) If you follow that example, I want:

```
SchoolEntities.Departments.First.Instructors
```

Comment: Do you specifically want `db.Mainlines.Find(4).Releases`, or is `db.Mainlines.Find(4).Builds.SelectMany(Function(b) (b.Releases))` sufficient? (Sorry if I got vb lambda syntax wrong, I was aiming for the equivalent of C#'s `b => b.Releases`)

Comment: Your first syntax is what I was expecting, coming from a Rails background. I just have never found an example of how to make that call before, in any way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following should work (though I've not tried it)

```
db.Mainlines
    .Where(Function(m) m.MainlineID = 4)
    .SelectMany(Function(m) m.Builds.SelectMany(Function(b) b.Releases))
.ToList()
```

Originally, I wrote this in C# so giving the same for reference:

```
db.Mainlines
    .Where(m => m.MainlineID == 4)
    .SelectMany(m => m.Builds.SelectMany(b => b.Releases))
.ToList();
```

Comment: I like Greg's terser syntax in his comment above, but, yes, the `.SelectMany()` is what I needed all along. I'd just never been able to find an example like mine to know this is what I needed to use.

Comment: Beware .Find (in Greg's comment) is one of the methods that cause immediate query evaluation. This means that the remaining query will be evaluated separately (so there will be two hits to the database which might not be desirable.). .Where is verbose but it's part of query building, and doesn't cause immediate query evaluation.

Comment: That's going to be an issue with the complexity and volume of queries. Thank you for pointing out the difference!

Comment: If you are using EF6, you can do `db.Database.Log = s => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(s);` 
it will show sql statements as they are generated and executed by dbcontext on output window.

Comment: Can you translate this to VB? I'm constrained to using it, despite the overwhelming preference for C# at large, and I've already wasted a couple hours never quite figuring out the syntax.

Comment: Ah yes, You have to always be aware whether you're in code or SQL. You could also chain, rather than nest the 2 `SelectMany` calls: `db.Mainlines.Where(Function(m) m.MainlineID = 4).SelectMany(Function(m) m.Builds).SelectMany(Function(b) b.Releases)`.